# Configure SonarQube using command line

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I'm running SonarQube 4.5.1 on Debian and I'd like to configure dashboards and rule profiles via [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/).

To do this, I can't use SonarQube's GUI but I have to use the command line to edit configuration files or call a CLI ([like the one Jenkins has](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI)).

I couldn't find a file in `/opt/sonar` or below that defines the dashboards or rule profiles.

Is there a way to configure SonarQube using only the command line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to achieve what you want to do will be to use the [SonarQube Web Service API](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Web+Service+API) with curl.

But:

- Only the [quality profiles can currently be managed with the WS API](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation#api/qualityprofiles), not the dashboards.
- You will have to explicitly pass admin credentials to the curl command - which might be a security issue for you